# Return value from one function to another with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

I am working on a login interface using the MEAN stack. I have managed to get it to work using PassportJS. My problem now is I need a way to let my client-side know whether the person logging in is an admin or user(user role). These info are available from my MongoDB.

The flow of my API call is as follow :

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), authRoutes.loginCheck);
```

First, it runs the passport.authenticate where it calls the function below

```
function verifyCredentials(username, password, done) // username & password from what user provide when logging in
{
    console.log('VC');
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) //query Mongo
    {
        console.log(user); // User role is available here, in JSON format
        if(user === null) // if no username in database, do this
        {
            console.log('Username does not exist in database');
        }
        else
        {
            user.comparePassword(password, function(err, match) // function written to compare hashed password in Mongo & password provided by user
            {
                if(match)
                {
                    done(null, {id: username, name: username});
                    return user; // this is not the correct syntax, but the idea is, I want to send over the user details here, so I can access the role later
                }
                else
                {
                    done(null, null);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The verifyFunction is called with this syntax.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(verifyCredentials));
```

Once that function is successfully called, the server executes the 2nd part of it which is the loginCheck.

```
module.exports.loginCheck = function(req, res)
{ 
    console.log('Calling loginCheck route');
    // I generate some sort of jwt token here
    // payload, body, blah blah blah ...
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({
                authenticated: req.isAuthenticated(), //built-in authentication function, returns true or false
                token: token // sends over token
                role: user.role // want to send over something like this    
            }); // sends all these to client side as JSON
}
```

Since both functions are in different files, I am unclear if I have to require something or simply just pass an extra parameter to the loginCheck function. I have tried the latter though and it did not work.

One way that I could think of is do another Mongo query in the loginCheck function, but that would be kinda redundant.

Even a specific keyword for me to google up would definitely be of big help as don't I know what I should be looking for. The reason is because I am new to NodeJS, thus I am not familiarize with most of the terms yet.

I think these codes should suffice but if I am needed to provide more, let me know and I will do so. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass control to next matching route you need to use `next` that passes as third argument in the routes:

```
function verifyCredentials(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) //query Mongo
    {
        if(user === null) {
            return next(new Error('Username does not exist in database'));
        } else {
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, match) {
                if(match) {
                    next(null, {id: username, name: username});
                } else {
                    next(new Error('not match'));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

app.post('/login', verifyCredentials, authRoutes.loginCheck);
```

Comment: where should I place the syntax to pass on the value of user so that the loginCheck function would be able to access it? or is it already accessible due to the next keyword?

Comment: If you specify 2 functions in routes and when you call `next`without error  in first function in will move control to next function. Where the `verifyCredentials` function  places and who calls this function?

Comment: `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(verifyCredentials));`
the above route uses the verifyCredentials function.

Comment: I managed to get it using your way @Talgat. Thank you so much.